# Pop-Up a message box when a Cell Value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where a column has a list validation.

When a particular entry from the list is selected, i need a message box to be popped up.

I could have used the following code if there was only 1 cell, but in my case i have many cells in a column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)    
    Dim rng As Range
       Set rng = Range("A1")
       If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
           If rng = "hi" Then
               MsgBox "Cell " & _
               rng.Address & " = hi"
           End If
       End If
       Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

examine the value of the Target.Column property ....

Suppose you want to examine column D (numeric value 4), you do

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 ' examine column D
    ' code to validate Target
        If Target = "xxx" Then MsgBox "You chose xxx from the list"
    End If
End Sub
```

Good luck MikeD